# checklist Conforming total autodesk

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

[image]

Does anyone know how the number in the cell under conforming is calculated in an Autodesk checklist?

Comment: Could you elaborate the context where the checklist form comes from? BIM360 Classic Field, BIM360 Field Management, or Autodesk Construction Cloud >> Form module? And it looks more about product question, instead of Forge which is about API programming. The forum of BIM360 might be more helpful https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-support/bd-p/183 , while after you elaborate, we can try best to check anything we could help.

Comment: The Checklist came from bim 360

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Thank you for the update. I posted an inquiry to our product support team, but it may be more helpful if you could also post this question on the link I shared last time, where the specialists of BIM360 products would share comment specifically